# Could SO mark Douglas Adams's Day?

Tags: feature-request

Sunday is Douglas Adams's Day (10/10/10). Could SO have a special Google style doodles to celebrate this once-in-a-century day? Or possibly something like the unicorn day?

Comment: `show tea and not tea to marvin`

Comment: There will be a celebration - that's when Ubuntu 10.10 comes out. Hooray!

Comment: @George: That is very appropriate considering Adam's love of all things techie.

Answer (score 2):

Its virtually impossible.

<sub>Now where's some hot tea...</sub>

Comment: [`SHARE AND ENJOY`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Share_and_Enjoy)

Comment: Did you mean infinity improbable?

Comment: @Zoredache - http://www.earthstar.co.uk/drive.htm

Comment: Right, of course it makes perfect sense.